# CMake inline functions undefined reference

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cygwin

I have a code base which I'm compiling for 2 different architectures. The one is `PowerPC` and the other is `x86`. For `PowerPC` I'm using a `Makefile` with `GCC` and the code base compiles just fine. For `x86` however I'm using `CMake` in [`CLion`](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) with `Cygwin` on `Windows` and I'm getting `undefined reference` errors for each called `inline` function:

```
CMakeFiles/my_project.dir/main.c.o: In function `wrapper_function':
/cygdrive/d/src/header.h:13: undefined reference to `inline_function'
/cygdrive/d/src/header.h:13:(.text+0x26): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `inline_function'
```

I made sure that all `inline` functions are in header files only. Also, I need them to be declared as `inline` because I want self-contained functions without sub procedures so removing that tag is not desired.

My `CMake` file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(my_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        main.c
        src/header.h)
add_executable(my_project${SOURCE_FILES})
```

How do I fix the linker error without changing the code base? If possible, an entry in the `CMake` file would be the optimal solution.

Comment: Could you post the code your error is referencing ?

Comment: This should have nothing to do with the build-system. Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the *code* to show us?

Comment: I actually realized using `static inline` everywhere fixes the problem

Comment: And if you wonder why you must be using `static inline` (and can't find a duplicate question, of which I'm certain there exists a few) then you should probably post that as a new question. Together with a MCVE!